# Laravel 4 eloquent constraint

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a `users` and a `orders` table. A user can have many orders and an order belongs to a user.

```
Users
id | name | email

Orders
id | user_id | name
```

So my User model is as follows:

```
class User extends Eloquent{
    public function orders(){
        return $this->hasMany('Order', 'user_id');
   }
}
```

My Order model:

```
class Order extends Eloquent{
    public function user(){
         return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
   }
}
```

Now, I have a Order controller, that will list the orders in the database. I want to list out the orders depending on the GET variable.

Eg: `www.domain.com/order?user=some+name`
 `www.domain.com/order?name=order+name`

For the second, I can do the following:

`$orders = Order::with('user')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('name') . '%')->get();`

But for the first one, the below code fails:

`$orders = Order::with('user')->where('user.name', 'LIKE', '%' . Input::get('user') . '%')->get();`

I have also tried this one:

```
$orders = Order::with(array('user' => function($q){
    $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . Input::get('user') . '%');
   }))->get();
```

This one returns all orders whether the user's name matches the GET string or not.

So, is there no way in eloquent that I can achieve the above? Is a manual JOIN the only way?

Comment: To my knowledge, with the current version, you can't filter the master table with a details table filter. You will either write this with raw SQL or Fluent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT BASED ON ASKERS COMMENTS**: Having said that you may need to access multiple table fields based on a filter/search. Here is one way to achieve it.

In your Order.php model, do something like:

```
public function scopeOrdersByQuery($query, $userName, $orderName)
{
    $query->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
        ->select(array('orders.*', DB::raw('users.name as user_name'), DB::raw('users.id as uid')));

    if (!empty($userName))
    {
       $query = $query->whereIn('users.user_name', $userName);
    }

    if (!empty($orderName))
    {
       $query = $query->whereIn('orders.name', $orderName);
    }
}
```

Add more table joins as necessary.

In your OrdersController do something like:

```
$userName = Input::get('userName');
$orderName = Input::get('orderName');

$orders = Order::ordersByQuery($userName, $orderName)->get();
```

Now you can either display all orders or search based on multiple queries or just one. Not tested but should work.

------------EDIT------------

I would use the users id if you wish to get all orders for a specific user.

In your Order.php model, do:

```
public static function getOrdersByUserId($userId)
{
    $orders = Order::with('user')->whereIn('user_id', $userId)->get();

    return $orders;
}
```

You can then pass this method the specific user id you are after by doing this in your OrdersController:

```
$userId = Input::get('user');

$orders = Order::getOrdersByUserId($userId);
```

Now, this is assuming that in your view you are adding a user id to the value of the input named 'user'.

You could also extend the getOrdersByUserId() method to accommodate a blank $userId value by using a scope method in your Orders.php model, like so:

```
public function scopeGetOrdersByUserId($query, $userId)
{
    $query->with('user');

    if(!empty($userId))
    {
        $query = $query->whereIn('user_id', $userId);
    }
}
```

Now in your controller, do:

```
$userId = Input::get('user');

$orders = Order::getOrdersByUserId($userId)->get();
// if paginating do $orders = Order::getOrdersByUserId($userId)->paginate(10);
```

Doing it this way would allow you to use this code in the index method of your OrdersController, thus allowing you to show all orders or specific user orders if an id was supplied.

**EDIT**: One thing I forgot to mention is, when generating your form, in your controller do:

```
$users = User::orderBy('name')->lists('name', 'id');
```

Then pass this variable to your view and use it to populate your user select box. I'm assuming you are using a select box to choose a user.

**EDIT**: As pointed out by @GladToHelp, you may want to add a constraint to an eagerly loaded model using Eager Load Constraints. You can do so by modifying the getOrdersByUserId() scope method in your Orders.php model to use the users name instead:

```
public function scopeGetOrdersByUserName($query, $userName)
{
    $query->with(array('user' => function($query2)
    {
        $query2->where('name', 'like', '%$userName%');
    }));
}
```

**NOTE**: This is untested code.

That said you may want to simply use:

```
$user = User::with('orders')->where('name', $name)->get();
```

Then use a foreach loop in your view on $user->orders.

Comment: I think he does not want to filter them by user_id. He wants to filter orders where the user name is passed by query string. You can see that the user.name field is part of the users table, so you can't just say: Order::with('user')->whereIn('user_id', $userId)->get();

Comment: @GladToHelp Yeah, I understand that mate but as I say in my answer, I would use the user id instead of the users name to get the orders. Not only would the query string look neater but it would still allow him to show the users name in a select box but the value submitted would be the users id. To be honest we don't know how he is passing the query string.

Comment: I agree on that. Passing an ID instead of username is a better approach, but I am afraid the root, general problem is a bit deeper in Laravel itself. It looks like Eloquent does not easily allow you to filter primary models based on constraints on eagerly loaded models at the moment.

Comment: @Gaz looks neat if only I were passing in the user IDs. But, in this case, I am trying to do a search for orders by the names of users. I can't possibly remember all the IDs of the user to pass user IDs.

Comment: @GladToHelp: Yes you can made. You simply use Eager Load Constraints. See my edit above.

Comment: @WebNovice Well in that case use Eager Load Constraints as detailed in my edit above.

Comment: @Gaz That will filter the users but in ALL orders. So you will get all orders and their users property will be filtered. The whole issue is that is that orders need to be filtered, but based on user's constraints.

Comment: @GladToHelp: Yup, you are right. Bit of a draw back that really.

Comment: @Gaz, I need to retrieve Orders and NOT users. So I can't use that `User::with..` . May be I have not explained my question properly. In my controller, I want to be able to search through orders based on different constraints. It could be a column on the `orders` table, or like the above example it could be a column on the `users` table, eg. user's name. So it definitely has to return Orders and not anything else.

Comment: @WebNovice using $user = User::with('orders')->where('name', $name)->get(); you're getting the order of that user based on the name you supply. Yes, you're loading the User but you're also pulling back their orders. Now, granted you are now talking about multiple queries on multiple tables/relationships. That's more complex.

Comment: @Gaz, the view file I am using, it has a foreach loop like `foreach($orders as $order)` and inside it, it has `$order->user->name`.  Now if I use `User::with('orders')` I can't reuse the view. I'll have to make a new view file for each function.

Comment: @WebNovice - Fair comment. Take a look at my edit above in my answer for filtering results based upon querying multiple tables/fields.

Comment: Now, it looks like something I can start off with and it should work. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Hope you get it working the way you want. Post back if you do.

Comment: @WebNovice You could even set it up to allow multiple values per input (maybe use select2), just make sure you use explode(',',Input::get('userName')); on your inputs, and also use the id of the record as the value when pulling it back via AJAX, as you could use an auto complete style input to pull back the correct records.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest to what you need: extend the model

```
 public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true){
        return parent::newQuery()->join('table','field1','=','field2');
    }
```

More info here:
http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=56659#p56659

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using JOINS as follows:

```
$orders = Order::with('user')
             ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
             ->where('users.name', 'LIKE', '%' . Input::get('name') . '%')->get();
```

The above example looks OK since am joining only two models/tables. But in my real application, I have 5 models that I eagerload with the Order, and it does get confusing, with table column name conflicts and all.

Wish there was a simpler way of doing it in Eloquent.